# Issues getting "ng-repeat" to repeat.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been trying this for awhile and I am not getting it. 
I looked at the documentation and I think it is my syntax.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-repeat="item in store.items">
        <img ng-src="{{item.ImageSets.ImageSet[0].SmallImage.URL}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("store", []);

    app.controller("StoreController", ["$http", function($http) {
        var store = this;
        store.items = []
        $http.get("/amazon.json").success(function(data) {
            store.items = data.Items
        });
    }]);
})();
```

And this is my object.

```
{
 "Items": {
     "Item": {...},
     "Item": {...},
     "Item": {...},
     "Item": {...}
  }
}
```

The code is working. But I am only getting it to display one image instead of 4 images. I am new to angular and think it is a syntax issue.

Comment: So maybe `item.ImageSets.ImageSet[0].SmallImage.URL` is defined only for one image?

Comment: try `item in store.items track by $index`

Comment: That's an invalid object. You can't have multiple identical keys in an object. Maybe you wanted to make an array instead?

Comment: I copy and pasted the Item so it would be the same because this is just sample code. So I do not think that is the issue.

Comment: Well maybe you should show the real thing instead? There's nothing wrong in the code itself so that's the only place I can think of where the problem might be.

Comment: @Juhana is correct. ng-repeat iterates over a collection. You have defined Items as an  object... not a collection. try <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div> to iterate over object properties

Comment: Here is the json. http://jsonblob.com/564b4ac2e4b01190df403c6c.

Comment: That JSON has only one item so I don't know why you expect to see 4?

Comment: I figured it out. I guess that it was the same, It was reading it as one. When I changed it to Item-1, Item-2, Item-3, Item-4 It worked.

Comment: @Juhana Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an angular issue, it's a JavaScript one. 
The thing is, you are trying to build an object with multiple times the same key (`item`).
So every time you add a new item to the object, the previous one gets erased. That is why your object only has a single item.

So doing :

```
var items = {
  "item": 1,
  "item": 2,
}
```

is equivalent to :

```
var items = {};
items["item"] = 1;
items["item"] = 2; //items["item"] gets replaced and its value is now 2
```

Instead you should use an array that contains all the items. Like that

```
{
    items: [
        {...},
        {...},
        //...
    ]
};
```